# SANE on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS not working (using Kodak Scanner, working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 18.04, scanner, sane, kodak

this is my first question on askubuntu, if i did a mistake, please tell me.

The Problem: I want to use my Kodak i2400 scanner on my PC with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (x64) installed.

I downloaded the official drivers from the manufacturer-page and installed it. During the installation there is the first inconsistency i noticed that the setup - the script says that SANE is not installed (but it is). 
So if i continue the installation despite the SANE is not recognized, it tells me the Software installation is complete and indeed in the folder /etc/sane.d/ there is a new file called kds_i2000.conf.

Now when i connect my scanner, nothing happens, i tried:
scanimage -L -> it tells me "No scanners were identified ..." 
sane-find-scanner -> it tells me "... No USB scanners found ..." 
starting xsane or gscan2pdf -> a popup shows "no devices available" and "no devices found"

So i tried using the same scanner on my notebook with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed and everything worked as expected, i was able to scan and none of this problems occur.

Has anything changed at the sane driver? i dont know why sane is not recognizing the scanner.

I would be very thankful for help,
regards

Comment: According to the scanners driver page, the driver was tested on Ubuntu 16.04. Until they come out with an updated driver, I don't think there is much you can do unless you revert back to Ubuntu 16.04.

Maybe others here will have an idea or two, however.

Comment: Ok, i sent a message to the support. They said they would forward that to the appropriate department.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply. This was my solution:

1. Disconnect scanner.
2. Download the official driver
3. Open terminal and install the driver (./setup)
4. run this command: `sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-kds* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`
5. Connect the scanner and scan

This solution was provided to me by kodak support.
Tested by me with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the program "simple scan".

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the problem that the XSane scanner did not show the pre-scan immage. Was all messed up. After deleting and re-install it refuses. Some library clash with N-Vidia driver. However simple scan keeps on working after the move to 18.04LTS